# Check if message was succesfully sent via whatsapp

Tags: android, whatsapp, instant-messaging, android-sharing

Good Day,

Im building an android app with a function of sharing a text message through whatsapp. Here is my code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message.toString());
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,""));
```

The code is working and I can share the message by choosing a contact and pressing send button in whatsapp.

My only problem is I need to go back from my activity and must know whether the message was successfully sent or not.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: WhatApp is a third party app. You can not access a single thing of Whatsapp in your code.

Comment: @jankigadhiya when I call the Intent, any thing that it can respond any response?

Comment: For that WhatsApp should return something like `Result.SENT`.. But the coding is not done by us. so We have no control over that.

Comment: @jankigadhiya we cannot access the Result.SENT?

Comment: Its just an example.. There is nothing like Result.SENT returned by WhatsApp. It **SHOULD** return I said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> whether the message was successfully sent or not.

Answer is **No** because **WhatsApp** does not have any api.

Comment: any workaround? I just only need to know whether it was sent or not.